# Get dependency type via Spring container at runtime

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Suppose I have following code to define `someBean`:

```
@Bean
public SomeInterface someBean() {
    return new SomeInterfaceImpl();
}
```

I want to get the interface type, namely`SomeInterface`, of this bean only from spring container at runtime. I tried the following code, but I found the `def` object knows nothing about `SomeInterface`.

```
ApplicationContext container = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext...
BeanDefinition def = container.getBeanDefinition("someBean");
```

Is it possible to get it only from the `container` object? If possible, please tell me how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find that you could get the implementation class SomeInterfaceImpl (by using String className = def.getBeanClassName())?  If so, using c = Class.forName(className), followed by c.getInterfaces() will yield SomeInterface.  This seems a bit clumsy; I don't know of a better option.

Comment: @IanMc But if `SomeInterface` extends another interface or `SomeInterfaceImpl` also implemented another interface, but I only want `SomeInterface`, how to determine it from multiple interfaces?

Comment: Right.  I often use context.getBeansOfType(SomeInterface.class) and Spring finds them - so there must be a way.  I will check in tomorrow to see what the correct answer is.